# loadchildren in different routing module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

i have been trying again with too many methods and stuck up with new scenario

below is my app.module.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Routes=[
    { 
      path: '', component: LoginComponent},
    { 
      path: 'maincontent', 
      loadChildren: './main-content/maincontent.module#MainContentModule'
    }]
```

below is my maincontent.module.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'maincontent',
    component: MainContentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', 
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    ] 
      }];
```

In dashboard.module.ts i have the following routes

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path:'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path:'application',component:ApplicationDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem is when i login i have navigated directly to the dashboard page and it doesn't show any contents of the page . Where am i going wrong can anyone guide me please

Comment: its not showing any error but the contents of dashboard component is not shown

Answer (score 1):

I was going through something similar but it turns out, I was missing a dependency...

In your case, @yurzui answer looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make `path` for child routes as empty string

**maincontent.module.ts**

```typescript
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // instead of path: 'maincontent',
    component: MainContentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
    ]
  }];
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```typescript
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // instead of path: 'dashboard'
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'application', component: ApplicationDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/g4UHBAcCLsY1OXjTjE8S?p=preview)**

Comment: empty string doesn't work it simply navigates to dashboard component

Comment: Where do you want to go after login? Why is it working in my example?

Comment: you have mentioned empty string in path i tried the same but instead of displaying login page it displays dashboard content

Comment: after logging in i want to navigate to dashboard where as maincontent has a toolbar and sidemenu and then when i click any side menu content that particular content should be loaded in that side menu one of the option is to render my dashboard content

Comment: In my example first you are on login page then you go to dashboard

Comment: I also added link to application details. You can check my plunker again

Comment: i have checked many times and applied the same i don't know what is wrong it just gives me the dashboard component content itself

Comment: if i mention path string as maincontent and dashboard  as mentioned in my question partially it works its just that it doesn't show content of my dashboard component